# How I can upload an oracle ddl file of 15M

Tags: configuration, database, oracle, oracle10g

I have a file of 15 mb and i need run the sql of that file in oracle, but when I try load the file, I have a error:

The file exceeds the maxim limit

When I can change that limit or how I can run that sql file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use Oracle Enterprise Manager for this.  Use [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html), sqlplus or another tool.

Answer (score 0):

Promt in console: sqlplus 'user/password@database' @file.sql